# For which $p>p^*$ does the inequality $\cos^2(−π/4+π/p)>1/2+π/p^2$​ hold?

Tags: inequalities, trigonometric-functions

I have the inequality $\cos^2(−\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{p})>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{π}{p^2}$​​ and have found that it holds for $p>p^*$, where $p^*$ is some positive number (around ~2.8). I'm looking for a way to determine $p^*$ and to prove the inequality for $p$ greater than this threshold. Any suggestions on approaches or relevant theorems would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You can differentiate the difference, show it's positive for positive $p$, and solve $\cos^2(\pi(\frac1x-\frac14))=\frac12+\frac\pi{x^2}$ numerically. It doesn't seem like this root has a closed form.

Comment: Actually the derivative is not always positive.  It becomes negative for $p>5.3$ approximately.  Asymptotically the function is $\pi/p$.

Comment: You may also write it as $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{p})>\frac{2\pi}{p^2}$ or $\sin(2\pi x)>2\pi x^2$, seeing their graphs could be clearer.

Comment: Would a series solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch:

Write $p=1/x$, so that you want to show
$f(x) = \sin(\pi/4+\pi x)-1/2-\pi x^2\ge 0$ for $0\le x\le 0.355$ approximately.

First, $f''(x)<0$ in $[0,1/2]$ (by a large margin), so $f'(x)$ is strictly decreasing in $[0,1/2]$. Moreover, $f'(0)>0$ and $f'(1/2)<0$, so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing up to a maximum, then strictly decreasing. Since $f(1/2)<0$, there is a single point in $(0,1/2)$ where it equals 0. You have to find that point numerically as there is almost certainly no closed expression. I get $x=1/2.8185102203577819$.

Comment: Why do you (confidently) say there is no closed expression?

Comment: I guess it is equivalent to find $X$ in $\sin(X)=aX^2$ for some $a$  see my comment.  It seems to be in an approximative way.

Comment: @mathworker21 I added "almost certainly". Equations like this only have closed-form solution in special cases, but admittedly I'm only 99% sure this is not one of them.